# "This customer email already exists" text error message

Tags: magento

Where is "This customer email already exists" text error message(My Account)?

In My account and on form where we try to change the email address. If we are trying to save the already exists email address we saw the error msg above.

I need to change something in that and tried looking around everywhere but could not find it. 
I find the form action pointing to `form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('customer/account/editPost')`

but editPostAction only seems to be handling the passwords change.

Can anyone please tell me where is it? which file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can change your error message from locale file of your magento setup

just go throw this path

```
yourproject\app\locale\en_US
```

open **`Mage_Customer.csv`** file and go to **`408`** line change second column text what you want to put with your new message

i hope this will solve your problem.

**Edit**

See below image  and change with your message in column b

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate little bit. How is it pointing to this specific line number and location.

Comment: And I tried but didn't work. I found the line and changed it but didn't work. I cleared the cache.

Comment: is your default us locale package is used ?

Comment: Yes that's what I did. I changed it in that file and cleared browser cache and tried it in 2 different browsers. Still the same

Comment: how to find if it's in use?

Comment: just go to for test : app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Resource\customer.php linr numbrt : 97 and try to change your message there and check it is comes from there or not and then chack again in csv files

Comment: Yes it's coming up from that file. Still wondering how is it pointing here. Anyways I just having to override this method now. Right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: but before you override whole method just check from which csv its comes from, you can do it with csv only without override files just check in your admin which locale package is using.

Comment: you can check it in admin under system->configuration-> left side general tab and select locale option of locale select box.

Comment: Yes it's English (Australia) not US. But now in en_AU there is no Mage_Customer.csv

Comment: you are using AU package for your project ?

Comment: if should be there or you can download package from here http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations

Comment: Yes, because its a Australian Website. In in the installation process when magento ask you to provide locale that where we choose. Why is it something wrong?

Comment: or you can also just copy and paste for magecustomer.csv if you dont want to replace whole package

Comment: some times magento default not providing all packages in magento setup we have to installed it later

Comment: clear your cache and browser cache also it should happen and please select from admin locale option as english australi

Answer (score 0):

You can change error message from csv translation file. just go to this location
app\locale\en_US.

Open Mage_Customer.csv file here you can find this error message. change error message here whatever you want.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. I found the line and changed it but didn't work. I cleared the cache. – RIK just now